PouchDB Sync not working after introducing CouchDB Proxy Authentication
I am using CouchDB on premise server and PouchDB-web for a react application to solve offline Sync Use case. Everything worked fine until we introduced a client side reverse-proxy for proxy authentication, authorization and to hide out the server/port no from the network tab.

the initial fetch works fine, but after the fetch i get a 404 Object Not Found GET error, and pouch db would not sync data up to couch or pull down from couchDb. Any help is appreciated. I have been scouting through forums and github for a month and still no where close to solution.

This is what my Get /_session looks like
{
"ok": true,
"userCtx": {
"name": null,
"roles": []
},
"info": {
"authentication_handlers": [
"cookie",
"proxy",
"default"
]
}
}

also how you all overcome with the browser limitation of 4-5 databases for pouchdb.

